# HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured (Hibernate4)

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations

I have been working on various issues to get this Spring-Hibernate app to work. I have probably made a basic error.

This seems to be a recurring question with many answers covering older versions of Hibernate. I am using Spring 4.3.9 and Hibernate 4.0.5

The UT gets a SessionFactory but getCurrentSession() is returning null and in debug I can see that currentSessionContext is null.

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <import resource="data.xml"/>
</beans>
```

data.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
>

<!-- Enable autowiring -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<!-- context:annotation-config/-->

<bean id="myDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.my"/>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool-size">1</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_cache">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
    <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
  </props>
</property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

SpringConfig.java

```
package utils.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@Import
(
  {SpringRepositoryConfig.class
  }
)

@ImportResource("classpath:configuration/applicationContext.xml")
public class SpringConfig
{
}
```

SpringRepositoryConfig.java

```
package utils.config;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import utils.persistence.ItemRepository;
import utils.persistence.HibernateItemRepositoryImpl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

// Declare as a configuration class
@Configuration
public class SpringRepositoryConfig
{
  @Autowired
  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  // Define repository bean
  @Bean
  public ItemRepository itemRepository()
  {
    ItemRepository rep = new HibernateItemRepositoryImpl();
    rep.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    return rep;
  }
}
```

SpringServicesConfig.java

```
package utils.config;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import bussysutils.persistence.ItemRepository;
import bussysutils.repository.DecoderLoadRepository;
import bussysutils.repository.DecoderLoadRepositoryImpl;


@Configuration
public class SpringServicesConfig
{
  @Inject
  ItemRepository repository;

  @Bean
  public DecoderLoadRepository decoderLoadRepository()
  {
    DecoderLoadRepositoryImpl decoderLoad = new DecoderLoadRepositoryImpl(repository);
    return decoderLoad;
  }
}
```

SessionConfig.java

```
package utils;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class SessionConfig
{

    public static SessionFactory buildFactory(String url
                                             ,String user
                                             ,String password)

  {
    ServiceRegistry sr;
    SessionFactory  sfactory;

    Configuration config = new Configuration();

    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",      url);
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb 
           = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties());

    sr = ssrb.build();

    try
    {
      sfactory = config.buildSessionFactory(sr);
    }
    catch (Throwable ex)
    {
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }

    return sfactory;
  }
}
```

UT_DecoderLoad.java

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import utils.DecoderLoad;

import utils.SessionConfig;

import utils.config.SpringConfig;

import utils.persistence.HibernateItemRepositoryImpl;
import utils.persistence.ItemRepository;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class UT_DecoderLoad
{

  @Autowired
  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Test
  public void decoderLoadTest()
  {

    try
    {
      DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

      sessionFactory = SessionConfig.buildFactory("jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my-host-name.my.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=dev)))"
                                                   ,"myuser"
                                                   ,"mypassword");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
      System.err.println("uploadServlet ERROR - " + e.getMessage());
      System.out.print("uploadServlet logon ERROR - SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();   ///  <<<<<<<<
    s.beginTransaction();

    DecoderLoad decoderLd = new DecoderLoad();

    decoderLd.setSiteRefNo("123456");
    System.out.println(decoderLd.getSiteRefNo());

    // update the database
    ItemRepository itemRepo = new HibernateItemRepositoryImpl();

    //    itemRepo.create(decoderLd);
    s.save(decoderLd);
    s.getTransaction().commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ditch your `SessioNConfig` class, you are using Spring to configure hibernate. From the configuration remove the `hibernate.current_session_context_class`. Also stop using `DriverManager.registerDriver` all that is done for you you are really complicating things. Finally configure your `DataSource` properly.

Comment: Removed current_session_Context, I only added it based on recommendations in other SO articles.
Removed registerDriver.

I want to be able to configure the datasource from values in a properties file which is why I have SessionConfig.

Comment: "Hard coding" the url, username and password into data.xml looks like it has fixed the currentSession issues.    Now it is returning  org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread  which might be due to packagesToScan, I am not sure it is scanning from the root folder.

Comment: Again don't use `SessionConfig`. Spring is perfectly capable of reading a properties file and replace the values. Instead of working around the framework I suggest to work with the framework. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer

Comment: I had removed SessionConfig from the UT but the transaction-synchronized error was the result. Thanks for you help with this.

Comment: Your test should be `@Transactional` to have a valid transactional context.

Comment: Do I also need a transactionManager bean in data.xml ?

Comment: Yes you do if you want Spring to manage your transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things very complicated for yourself, first you are mixing XML and Java based configuration and you have a configuration class for single beans. Either use Java or XML but don't mix them, especially if you aren't sure what those things do.

Your `DataSource` setup is also flawed as it is a partially setup `DataSource`.

Next your `SessionFactory` configuration is basically useless due to the use of the `SessionConfig` (which basically renders your Spring configuration useless). You shouldn't be using the `SessionConfig`, so drop it. Your `SessionFactory` configuration in the XML is also flawed, the `hibernate.connection` properties don't do anything, due the the injected `DataSource` and you shouldn't be messing around with the `hibernate.current_session_context` property unless you are using JTA. Spring will manage it for you.

Your unit test is also flawed, you should be injecting the repository not creating a new instance yourself.

That being said and moving everything to xml your `data.xml` should look something like this.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

   <tx:annotation-driven/>
   <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties" />

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
      <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
      <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.my"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_cache">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernatTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="itemRepository" class="utils.config.HibernateItemRepositoryImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="decoderLoadRepository" class="utils.config.DecoderLoadRepositoryImpl">
    <constructor-arg  ref="itemRepository" />
  </bean>  
</beans>
```

The `jdbc.properties` would contain the following

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my-host-name.my.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=dev)))
jdbc.username=myuser
jdbc.password=mypassword
```

You can now drop your `SessionConfig`, `SpringServicesConfig` and `SpringRepositoryConfig` classes as the first you shouldn't have in the first place the config class are obsolete due to adding the context to the xml file.

Now your test is also flawed as it should be `@Transactional` and should load the XML file instead of the java config.

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:configuration/applicationContext.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class UT_DecoderLoad {

  @Autowired
  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Test
  public void decoderLoadTest() {

    Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();   ///  <<<<<<<<
    DecoderLoad decoderLd = new DecoderLoad();

    decoderLd.setSiteRefNo("123456");
    System.out.println(decoderLd.getSiteRefNo());

    s.save(decoderLd);
    s.flush(); // "simulate a commit"
  }
}
```

Although not sure what you are testing here, you should probably be testing the `HibernateItemRepositoryImpl`.

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:configuration/applicationContext.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class UT_DecoderLoad {

  @Autowired
  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Autowired
  ItemRepository repository

  @Test
  public void decoderLoadTest() {

    DecoderLoad decoderLd = new DecoderLoad();
    decoderLd.setSiteRefNo("123456");

    repository.create(decoderLd);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush(); // "simulate a commit"

    // Validate the existence in the database
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was working on adding a jdbc.properties file (I had tested with one previously) and had all ready removed SessionConfig.   I have now removed the other config classes and made most of the other changes. I had to change the itemRepository bean to `utils.persistence.HibernateItemRepositoryImpl`  and   decoderLoadRepository bean to `utils.repository.DecoderLoadRepositoryImpl`   I also simplified the UT as you described above.   When it reaches the `s.save(decoderLoad);`  in HibernateItemRepositoryImpl it throws `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: utils.DecoderLoad`

Comment: Well I copied your code so probably the `packagesToScan` isn't correct.

Comment: With a few more changes (I will post the code shortly) it is now running but not committing a record to the database. Does `flush` commit  ?

Comment: A `@Transactional` test will rollback after the test execution (I suggest a read of the spring testing chapter in the reference guide).

Answer (score 0):

This is my current version, it runs but does not update the db table.

data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
>
  <!-- Enable autowiring -->
  <tx:annotation-driven/>

  <context:property-placeholder location="resources/jdbc.properties"/>

  <bean id="DataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url"      value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="utils"/>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_cache">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
        <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>

  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

    <bean id="itemRepository" class="utils.persistence.HibernateItemRepositoryImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="decoderLoadRepository" class="utils.repository.DecoderLoadRepositoryImpl">
    <constructor-arg  ref="itemRepository" />
  </bean>  

</beans>
```

UT_DecoderLoad.java

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import utils.DecoderLoad;
import utils.persistence.ItemRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@ContextConfiguration("classpath:configuration/applicationContext.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class UT_DecoderLoad
{

  @Autowired
  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Autowired
  ItemRepository itemRepo;

  @Test
  public void decoderLoadTest()
  {

    DecoderLoad decoderLd = new DecoderLoad();

    decoderLd.setSiteRefNo("123456");
    decoderLd.setDecoderNo("999");
    System.out.println(decoderLd.getSiteRefNo());

    itemRepo.create(decoderLd);

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
  }
}
```

I added a primary key column into the db table so that I could add the required @Id

DecoderLoad.java

```
package utils;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

@Entity
@Table(name = "Decoder_Load")

public class DecoderLoad
{

  public DecoderLoad()
  {
  }

  // pojo with annotations

  @Id
  @Column(name = "decoder_no")
  private String decoderNo;
  ...
```

I also added javassist to the pom.

Maven compile complains:

```
package org.springframework.test.context does not exist
package org.springframework.test.context.junit4 does not exist
```

This simple test runs but it is not inserting a record without forcing it and causing other issues.

EDIT:  just learned that a test does a rollback so it will not commit.